# How to call button in Partial View from jQuery script (MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing application who has few forms. In main view I have for example:

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<button id="bt1">Click from main view</button>

<div id="partial">

</div>
```

and then i call btn1 from script:

```
$("#bt1").click(function () {
        alert("btn1click");
    });
```

and also render the partial view:

```
$("#partial").load("/Home/Home");
```

and then call the second button:

**Partial view:**

```
<h4>Partial view</h4>
<button id="btn2">Click from partial view</button>
```

**Script:**

```
 $("#btn2").click(function () {
        alert("btn2click");
    });
```

but this action do nothing. I have no idea why. Can you help me?
How can I call the button from script?
I'm using ASP.NET MVC but for some reasons I can't use RenderPartial method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation like

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn2', function () {
        alert("btn2click");
    });
```

Basically, regardless of when `#btn2` is loaded, this event should fire because it was delegated from the document. This is saying for all **current** and **future** `#btn2` elements, execute this click handler